# Cannot upload file for my mulitpart api from swagger(No choose file option available) in spring boot project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am unable to upload file as for my api as there is not upload option available on swagger ui.[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q555i.jpg)

My swagger configuration class -

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket fileUploadApi(){

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.spicemoney.fileupload.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().apiInfo(metaInfo());

    }

}
```

My api mapping -

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadFile", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public List<String> uploadFile(@RequestPart("files") MultipartFile[] files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that swagger ui donot support multiple files for selection. It works fine if I take MultipartFile instead of MultipartFile[].